# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in .dll that used in client applcation

Tags: c#, dll

I am using one of the .dll in my application and when I try to debug the code below of the .dll ,I am getting an error as given below when try to execute the "serializer.Serialize(writer, preAdvice); " portion.

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'"

```
PreAdviceOrder preAdvice = new PreAdviceOrder();
preAdvice.Items = purchaseOrders.ToArray();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(preAdvice.GetType());
//fs = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
//serializer.Serialize(fs, preAdvice);
var writer = new XmlTextWriter(_fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
serializer.Serialize(writer, preAdvice);
```

Can anyone help to find what the exact issue is?

Comment: What did the stack trace look like on the exception?

Comment: @RowlandShaw IIRC you cant see the stack trace for `StackOverflowException`

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453476/why-do-i-get-a-system-stackoverflowexception-was-unhandled-exception-when-ser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168573/stackoverflowexception-in-xml-to-c-sharp-class

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You can in the debugger. It's also nigh on impossible to solve a Stack Overflow without spotting the repeated call sequence on the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stack overflow exception happens when you put too much on the stack. That's hard to get without recursion. There are two possible errors that may lead to such an exception:

- The code you posted is somehow called recursively. Check your recursion end condition.
- Your object to serialize holds references to itself. Then the serializer will recurse on it's own. For example if your purchaseOrders hold references to their parent.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: the data stored in the `PreAdviceOrder` (from whatever framework that is) has circular reference, e.g. parent to child and child to parent. That causes an infinite recursion when trying to serialize the object and its references and thus eventually a stack overflow.

Comment: In that case it will throw `InvalidOperationException` saying *A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type XXX*

Comment: I just had a look at the `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` and the classes used by it. I can't see a point where that would be detected. I know that _some_ serializers detect circular references e.g. Json.Net. Do you have a reference to where that happens in this case?