# How to control the de-serialisation of a complex object

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, serialization

I call a third party web service that returns a HUGE amount of XML Data (around 2mb) and I want to deserialise it into an object in a more controlled way than normal. This is the xml:

```
<vehicle>
  <vehicleManufacturer>
    <type>1</type>
    <name>A Make</name>
  </vehicleManufacturer>
...
```

I know I can do the below code to control which elements are serialised to which properties, in this case the Car Make object contains two properties, type and name.

```
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("vehicleManufacturer")> _
    Public Property Make() As CarMake
```

But what I want to be able to do, if possible, is to deserialise just the name field into the Make property, or even just serialise that whole element and it's contents to text.

```
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("vehicleManufacturer")> _
    Public Property Make() As String
```

This is a hugely simplified example, so if there are any resources that would help me with this, that would be great.

Another example:

```
<vehicle>
  <warrantyDetail>
    <warrantyBasicInformation buildStartdate="09/07/2013" warrantyStartDate="31/07/2013"/>
  </warrantyDetail>
</vehicle>
```

I'd like to get the attributes out of warrantyBasicInformation without having to build the warranty detail and warrantyBasicInformation objects.

Note that this sort of thing would usually be generated from the WSDL, however, I won't be provided with one, I don't have an XSD, and [trying to generate](http://thesoftwarearchitect.com/generate-c-class-xml-file/) one failed. I also know I can implement ISerializable and use an xml reader or linq, but again, that can turn into a lot of code and maybe hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling this is a code smell, but its the easiest method I've come up with. (it assumes that nodes are going to exist etc, which in this case is ok.)

```
Using tr As IO.TextReader = New IO.StringReader(strResult)

  Using reader As System.Xml.XmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(tr)

    reader.MoveToContent()

    While reader.Read

      If reader.NodeType = Xml.XmlNodeType.Element Then

        Select Case reader.Name

          Case "warrantyDetail"

            Dim xel As XElement = CType(XNode.ReadFrom(reader), Xml.Linq.XElement)

            If xel IsNot Nothing Then

              vi.RegCountry = xel.Element("country").Element("name").Value
              vi.Reg = xel.Element("registration").Value
              xel.Element("warrantyBasicInformation").Attribute("buildStartdate").Value
              xel.Element("warrantyBasicInformation").Attribute("buildStartdate").Value
              ...

            End If

          Case ...

        End Select
      End If    
    End While
  End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation some weeks ago where Microsoft's xsd.exe, which you tried to use, failed to generate a reasonable XML schema. I solved the problem using [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html), which did the job perfectly. I then used xsd.exe to automatically generate wrapper classes.

This might not fully answer your question, but your life should be easier with an xsd schema.

Comment: Looks useful, and the XSD generated correctly, but using XSD to generate the classes produced about 10 errors saying: "Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance:type' attribute is not declared. Line 376, position 8."   
and then Warning: "Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results. No classes where generated."

Answer (score 2):

We have been using [Xsd2Code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com) for a while for reading xml files. All these files have an XSD behind it that helps generation (I think XSD is the only way you get this sorted out without a lot of hand-crafted code, if giving problems, try to write it yourself, it isn't that hard).

Xsd2Code generates a code file with Serialize and Deserialize methods like this:

```
repositoryAsXml = settings.Serialize();
```

and

```
icn_database_v database;

if (!icn_database_v.Deserialize(xmlContents, out database, out exception))
{
    throw exception;
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid as much manual work as possible due to time constraints... the object is HUGE and I don't need all the data contained, I just wanted to cherry pick a few elements. I don't have an XSD, so I'm not sure how Xsd2Code will help?

Comment: We were using the solution you tried first too (generating xsd, and use xsd.exe to generate C# classes). This didn't work out for us either. Xsd2Code has a better way of generating code from XSD.

So when you pick up the sample xml, generate XSD from it (using Visual Studio or online tools) and generate code from it, it needs no manual work (we use an automated build script that does this all for us).

Comment: I've tried a number of tools to get XSD from XML, but they either have an error, or produce an inaccurate XSD. I assume its inaccurate as Xsd2Code has errors when serialising and deserialising, with the message "There was an error reflecting type" and "Inconsistent sequencing: if used on one of the class's members, the 'Order' property is required on all particle-like members, please explicitly set 'Order' using XmlElement, XmlAnyElement or XmlArray custom attribute on class member 'vin'."

Comment: If you have an example I would be glad to help you on this one.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, but the XML is 11221 lines and full of sensitive information so I am unable to share it.

Comment: That is an awful lot of XML ;). We are handling files of 500K lines so I know the feeling (when using Xsd2Code, the max we use is about 2K). If you need assistance later on please PM me.

Comment: No, only what I answered below. It works, but I ran out of time to find a "proper" solution (... usually seems to be the case with commercial software)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need strong types, consider the following roll-your-own solution by @Esen at [XML class generator for serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335828/xml-class-generator-for-serialization/10353093#10353093):

```
namespace Utility1 
{
public static class XMLHelper
{
   private enum XMLType
   {
      Element,
      Attribute
   }
    public static string GenerateXMLClass(string xmlstring)
    {
        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        xd.LoadXml(xmlstring);
        XmlNode rootNode = xd.DocumentElement;
        var xmlClassCollection = new Dictionary<string, XMLClass>();
        var xmlClass = new XMLClass();
        xmlClassCollection.Add(rootNode.Name, xmlClass);
        CollectAttributes(ref xmlClass, rootNode);
        CollectElements(ref xmlClass, rootNode);
        CollectChildClass(ref xmlClassCollection, rootNode);

        var clsBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        clsBuilder.AppendLine("[XmlRoot(\"" + rootNode.Name + "\")]");

        foreach (var cls in xmlClassCollection)
        {
            clsBuilder.AppendLine("public class " + cls.Key);
            clsBuilder.AppendLine("{");

            foreach (var element in cls.Value.Elements)
            {
                if (XMLType.Element == element.XmlType)
                    clsBuilder.AppendLine("[XmlElement(\"" + element.Name + "\")]");
                else
                    clsBuilder.AppendLine("[XmlAttribute(\"" + element.Name + "\")]");
                clsBuilder.AppendLine("public " + element.Type + element.Name + "{get;set;}");
            }

            clsBuilder.AppendLine("}");
        }

        return clsBuilder.ToString();
    }

    private static void CollectAttributes(ref XMLClass xmlClass, XmlNode node)
    {
        if (null != node.Attributes)
        {
            foreach (XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
            {
                if (null == xmlClass.Elements.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Name == attr.Name))
                    xmlClass.Elements.Add(new Element("string ", attr.Name, XMLType.Attribute));
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool IsEndElement(XmlNode node)
    {
        if ((null == node.Attributes || node.Attributes.Count <= 0) &&
                   (null == node.ChildNodes || !node.HasChildNodes || (node.ChildNodes.Count == 1 && node.ChildNodes[0].NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void CollectElements(ref XMLClass xmlClass, XmlNode node)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (null == xmlClass.Elements.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Name == childNode.Name))
            {
                var occurance = node.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().Where(o => o.Name == childNode.Name).Count();
                var appender = "  ";
                if (occurance > 1)
                    appender = "[] ";

               if(IsEndElement(childNode))
                {
                    xmlClass.Elements.Add(new Element("string" + appender, childNode.Name, XMLType.Element));
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlClass.Elements.Add(new Element(childNode.Name + appender, childNode.Name, XMLType.Element));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void CollectChildClass(ref Dictionary<string, XMLClass> xmlClsCollection, XmlNode node)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (!IsEndElement(childNode))
            {
                XMLClass xmlClass;
                if (xmlClsCollection.ContainsKey(childNode.Name))
                    xmlClass = xmlClsCollection[childNode.Name];
                else
                {
                    xmlClass = new XMLClass();
                    xmlClsCollection.Add(childNode.Name, xmlClass);
                }
                CollectAttributes(ref xmlClass, childNode);
                CollectElements(ref xmlClass, childNode);
                CollectChildClass(ref xmlClsCollection, childNode);
            }
        }
    }

    private class XMLClass
    {
        public XMLClass()
        {
            Elements = new List<Element>();
        }
        public List<Element> Elements { get; set; }
    }

    private class Element
    {
        public Element(string type, string name, XMLType xmltype)
        {
            Type = type;
            Name = name;
            XmlType = xmltype;
        }
        public XMLType XmlType { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, if you just want to speed up some of the typing overhead:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Here's a free tool that may be useful:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplexmltocode/