# Are there any tools to autogenerate C# classes from xml?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

We have xml from a REST API and are currently handwriting POCO's for them.  I vaguely recall that there were tools to do this automagically in Visual Studio.

What is the best way to generate POCO's from XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use xsd.exe to do so.

To create an xsd file:

```
xsd file.xml /outputdir:"C:\Temp"
```

To create classes from the xsd file:

```
xsd file.xsd /classes /outputdir:"C:\Temp"
```

Answer (score 1):

[xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.71).aspx) might be what you are looking for.

This post shows how to make the c# class from the generated schema:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133052/353147